# Unable to buy travel insurance for Kosovo in New Zealand

Tags: insurance

A friend of mine wants to travel to Kosovo but she is unable to buy travel insurance in New Zealand because none of the insurance companies will sell a policy which covers "high-risk" countries, even though most of Kosovo is classified as "some risk" like France and Germany: see [www.safetravel.govt.nz](https://www.safetravel.govt.nz/)

Is there any way to buy travel insurance in New Zealand which is valid for Kosovo? Possibly buying it from an overseas company for example?

Comment: It might have more to do with Kosovo's uncertain legal situation than with risk *per se*. Unfortunately, I don't know any answer…

Answer (score 2):

Kosovo is is a "partially recognized state". They are not recognized by the United Nation.

In theory, you could find insurances that include Kosovo within Serbia.

I doubt you could really find one in NZ as their job is to be as cautious as possible. But in theory, if their contract don't specify it, Kosovo ⊂ Serbia